# Translation doesn't work on breadcrumbs added by xml

Tags: localisation

I'm building a custom page.

I add breadcrumbs like this (and it works well).

```
<brand_brand_index translate="label">
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link>/</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>All Brands</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>All Brands</label>
                    <title>All Brands</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
        [[...]]
    </brand_brand_index>
```

The problem is label not translated in front-end. It shows `Home / All Brands` instead of translated version.

The things I made sure:

1. Added `translate="label"` to handler
2. Cache cleared (acctually I turned off caching)
3. Translation syntax is correct (I put in Mage_Core.csv)
4. Label is translated properly by php code (eg: `$helper->__('All Brands');`

Help me to figure it out, please.

Thank you.

Comment: When adding `translate="label"` did you also include `module="brand_brand"` (or whatever it should be in your case)?

Comment: `<crumbInfo translate="label" module="brand_brand">` - See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550429/about-translate-label-attribute-in-magento-how-does-it-work

Comment: Thank you @pspahn, I try and tell you later. Just a minute. Thank you.

Comment: In your link, the answer says `If the module attribute is not present, the core module is used.`
I add translate term in Mage_Core.csv in the beginning, so why doesn't still work? 
I just add module name (and module translation file as well) but it still doesn't work. 

I keep inspecting. A minute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To translate a crumb without using a helper, you can use the `translate` attribute for your `action` node by using `crumbInfo.label` and `crumbInfo.title`.

Exemple:

```
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
        <crumbName>home</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo>
            <label>Home</label>
            <title>Home</title>
            <link>/</link>
        </crumbInfo>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
        <crumbName>brands</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo>
            <label>All Brands</label>
            <title>All Brands</title>
        </crumbInfo>
    </action>
</reference>
```

It's the better way to translate breadcrumbs, use helpers only if you have the set a custom title depend on URL params or something else.

Comment: Thank you Frederic. Simple but it works. I've tried it in Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: @PeterJaapBlaakmeer Thanks! Yes, I really think my answer should be the accepted answer. It's easier and you don't need another helper.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted because I find it easier to do in many cases. Thank you. Your answer came quite late when I got it done long time ago, that's why it was not be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also generate links for breadcrumbs using helper class.
Using helper class, above XML block may look like:

```
<brand_brand_index translate="label">
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <params helper="module/getHomeUrl" />
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>All Brands</crumbName>
            <params helper="module/getBrandUrl" />
        </action>
    </reference>
    [[...]]
</brand_brand_index>
```

And add the `getHomeUrl()` & `getBrandUrl()` methods in your module's Helper/Data.php as:

```
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    //...

    public function getHomeUrl()
    {
        return array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Home'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Home'),
            'link' => Mage::getUrl(),
        );
    }

    public function getBrandUrl()
    {
        return array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('All Brands'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('All Brands')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but do you have any idea on why the translation doesn't work if you use the `<crumbInfo><label></label></crumbInfo>`-way?

Comment: Have posted my answer below, im unable to get the proper breadcrumbs in my custom module

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same as below:

in my xml file:

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <params helper="recipe/getHomeUrl" />
                <!-- <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link>/</link>

                </crumbInfo> -->
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Recipes</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Recipes</label>
                    <title>Recipe Home Page</title>
                    <link>/recipe</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Current Page</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Current Page</label>
                    <title>Current Page</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

**\app\code\local\Magenshop\Recipe\Helper\Data.php**

```
public function getHomeUrl()
{
    return array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Home'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Home'),
        'link' => Mage::getUrl(),
    );
}
```

Im getting only:

1)   /Recipes/Current Page

2) No Home page link...

Comment: Make sure your extensions name is "recipe", not "magenshop/recipe".